# SSH to created container

Tags: ssh, ip, lxc

I create container through `lxc-create -t ubuntu -n hadoop24`. But I can not ssh to ubuntu@hadoop,  I can ssh to ubuntu@10.0.3.205.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname hadoop24: Name or service not known
```

Actually <10.0.3.205> is hadoop24's IP. I added  to the hosts file. What's the problem?

Comment: What's the output of `grep hadoop /etc/hosts`?

Comment: @Sebastian Stark, Yes I added my another hostname into `/etc/hosts` on all hosts. `grep hadoop /etc/hosts` : `127.0.1.1 hadoopmaster
hadoopmaster 192.168....
hadoop24 10.0....
hadoop25 10.0....    
hadoop26 10.0....   
hadoop27 10.0.3.235`

Comment: I can not find "hadoop" in the output, nor the IP address you are mentioning. Are you sure you added a line there that reads `10.0.3.111 hadoop`?

Comment: Excuse me, I write "hadoop" in question while it is hadoop24 or hadoop25... I edited my question.

Comment: @ Sebastian Stark, I'm sure to what you say.